# How to remove white Space which is showing after click on drop down

Tags: jquery

i want to remove white Space after click on drop down

```
<select name="shipping_method" class="required-entry" id="shipping_method" style="width:250px;">
   <optgroup disabled="disabled" style="font-style: normal; display: none; visibility: hidden;" label="Free Shipping">
      <option style="display: none;" value="freeshipping_freeshipping">
         Standard Shipping (SmartPost) (2 - 7 Business Days) - $0.00                                                    
      </option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup style="font-style: normal; display: inline; visibility: visible;" label="FedEx">
      <option value="fedex_FEDEX_GROUND">
         Ground - $22.01                                                    
      </option>
      <option value="fedex_FEDEX_2_DAY">
         2-day (2 - 3 Business Days) - $41.04                                                    
      </option>
      <option value="fedex_STANDARD_OVERNIGHT">
         Standard Overnight ( 1 - 2 Business Days) - $58.87                                                    
      </option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

I am using below code to hide & disabled Free shipping its working fine but there is white space is showing in place of Free shipping its not visible but its taking space

```
$j("#shipping_method optgroup[label='Free Shipping']").css('visibility', 'hidden');
$j("#shipping_method optgroup[label='Free Shipping']").attr("disabled", true);
$j("#shipping_method optgroup[label='FedEx']").css('visibility', 'visible');
$j("#shipping_method optgroup[label='FedEx']").attr("disabled", false);
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/q4onbpzr/

Comment: Could you add some kind of fiddle ? Makes it a lot easier to help you solving your problem. And what white space you talking about ?

Comment: please provide us some pen or jsfiddle sample links so we can help you

Comment: @bellabelle i allready gave him the hint ^^

Comment: @Dwza - hehe sorry

Comment: @Dwza : i added js fiddle please check on IE browser i first option is showing in white space i want to remove that white sapce

Comment: you mean above the FedEx ?

Comment: @Dwza : yes above Fedex White space is there if you will open in Internet Explorer rest browser its working fine

Comment: @Dwza : Did you understand what i need

Comment: @magento12345 yes, see my post. This should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below one example first do clone outside the select & then remove the option & when you need append the outside clone option

```
$("#shipping_method optgroup[label='Free Shipping']").clone("optgroup[label='Free Shipping']").insertAfter("#shipping_method_form");
    $("#shipping_method optgroup[label='Free Shipping']").remove();
    $(".box-content .fedex").appendTo("#shipping_method");
```

Answer (score 1):

IE do not support `style="display:none;"` on `<option>` tags.

You could use the `.remove()` method from jquery to solve this behavior.

```
$("#shipping_method optgroup[label='Free Shipping']").remove();
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmbLqwu2/

In my IE 11 it looks like...

[image]

guess the yellow part should be removed. So after my solution it looks like

[image]

Comment: In your jsFiddle, the white space is still there under label="FedEx" :)

Comment: @bellabelle In my IE there was no whitespace any more

Comment: I'll give you a plus :)

Answer (score 0):

Not too Sure! is this the only approach you want to take. IE does not support display none or visibility: hidden; on option

Can you may try different way.

Like using jquery Remove and add functionality.

when required add it when not remove it.

Here is sample working version That may help you to get an idea

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MMRahman/mjdt67ok/6/)

```
<select name="shipping_method" class="required-entry" id="shipping_method" style="width:250px;">
```

Ground - $22.01
      
      
          2-day (2 - 3 Business Days) - $41.04
      
      
          Standard Overnight ( 1 - 2 Business Days) - $58.87

Hide
Show

Comment: Are you answering here or asking?

Comment: can you please update that fiddle as per your explanation to use add or remove

Comment: `For some wired reason IE does not always like display none or visibility: hidden;` Actually its not "for some reason" or "not allways". It's simply a not implemented behavior for specific html elements. I think its just missing options...

Comment: @magento12345 Can you please check JSFIDDLE which I provide and let me know if you have any more confusion

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/mjdt67ok/)

Below `whitespace` was removed. I used `click` event in `jquery` and added if else condition. `1` value equals to open state else closed state.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: ah okay wait, i have a question, you only want to remove the white space below the area of the select, right? the big white space

Comment: ah okay that is what you mean, hehe okay :)

Comment: @bellabelle Your fiddle is not working on my IE, i'm using IE 11 (ok, i'm not using it... i just have it) and my fiddle is working very well